# Java connect to docker with unix socket

Tags: java

I would like connect with java to docker with unix socket for example:

`curl --unix-socket /run/docker.sock 'http://docker/containers/json'`

or

`curl --unix-socket /run/docker.sock 'http://docker/events?filters=%7B%22ev.....'`

can you recommend a library that can do that and how? I am java beginner it is my first project.

Comment: @maio290 I don't think this question is about connecting to services inside a container.

Comment: @OhleC You're right, I guess the first line of the question got me confused ;)

Comment: [JEP 380](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/380) implemented in Java 16 brings that ability to core Java

Comment: sorry, I need get list of docker containers or another data via java app.